# I want the code whih make like that at inno-setup (send file to temporary Folder and call it Through button)

Tags: inno-setup

When I open the  Installation file
It send file to temporary Folder

I want to make lik that (I want the code) 
and
when the user press this button  it open the file which I choose before
(I want the code which it make all)
and don't tell me read any help or any paper
Because I do it and I understand it but I can't make it.

I want to make the about button to open the filer witch extracted to ehe temporary Folder when the user press it ,like this Installation file

the folder witch the file extracted in is  "IS-XXXX.temp" and it change every time the user open the Installation file and I can't know sure the path of the file every time.

so that : ExtractTemporaryFile('filename.rtf')
I can't understand it !!!

Or how I can use the temporary file Through the button if the path change every time. I see  what I want in this picture  but I can't make like it.
http://i53.tinypic.com/dc8z7p.jpg

How can I connect the button to the temporary file?

Comment: If you understood a given reference for InnoScript that deals with your question, you would be able to implement it. So, in essence no, you did not understand it. Being that as it may, your question is not really intelligible, so I have to ask you to revise it, put it in proper wording etc. so people don't have such a hard time finding out what you are really after. And please refrain from making your whole post bold - that really defeats the meaning of formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for any one want this

see

http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=89926&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#89926

thanks